# How to combine two laravel apps in one with Vue.js frontend

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

after some new elements comming into play, I have now two Laravel applications with Vue.js as frontend. Both have separate databases.

One was on a LAN and didn't have authentication. The other one is hosted on a webserver and has authentication.

I now need to host the first one aswell and share data between the two apps and need one authentication that works for both.

My guess was to merge the databases to allow for key constraints.

I don't know to proceed with the laravel apps and frontends though. Do I just dump the models, controllers and routes into one app and then do the same with the frontend and have a button for switching for the app I want to use?

Thanks for reading

Edit:

Authentication method : Default Laravel Authentication method

Vue.js : Both applications are SPAs

Sharing APP_KEY : Not implemented

Routes : I don't know if splitting the two on two different subdomains or merging them has to be done so I can't really answer this

Comment: This is impossible to answer without critical pieces of information: What is your existing authentication mechanim? is the Vue app an SPA? Are you using JWT? Can you share the `APP_KEY` between both Laravel instances? How will you know which Laravel application to route a specific request to? That's just the start of it. For these reasons, I'm requesting that you be more specific with your issue and focus in on one detail at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm going to add the specifications. @Ohgodwhy

Comment: Not a great question, there's no one way to do it and it's going to be up to preference, but I'd venture to guess that subdomaining each app web be the simplest way to integrate, but may the to be harder to maintain over time